# Get only the main page from an URL using regex

Tags: r, regex, string, gsub

I am trying to get the name of several webpages and this is an example of the dataset that I have:

```r
c("https://arealdata-api.miljoeportal.dk/download/dai/BES_NATURTYPER_SHAPE.zip", 
"https://download.kortforsyningen.dk/content/matrikelkortet", 
"https://b0902-prod-dist-app.azurewebsites.net/geoserver/wfs", 
"https://sit-ftp.statens-it.dk/main.html", 
"https://arealdata.miljoeportal.dk/datasets/saerligtudpejede", 
"https://miljoegis3.mim.dk/spatialmap?profile=privatskovtilskud", 
"https://envs.au.dk/fileadmin/envs/Hjemmeside_2018/Zip_filer/Basemap03_public_geotiff.zip", 
"https://arealdata-api.miljoeportal.dk/download/dai/BES_VANDLOEB_SHAPE.zip", 
"https://wfs2-miljoegis.mim.dk/vp3basis2019/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetCapabilities", 
"httphttps://datasets.catalogue.data.gov.dk/dataset/ramsaromrader", 
"https://ens.dk/service/statistik-data-noegletal-og-kort/download-gis-filer", 
"https://miljoegis.mim.dk/cbkort?profile=miljoegis-raastofferhavet", 
"https://www.marineregions.org/", 
"https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=geodata>.", 
"https://miljoegis3.mim.dk/spatialmap?profile=vandprojekter", 
"https://landbrugsgeodata.fvm.dk/")
```

As an example for the first entry, I want to get the webpage *"https://arealdata-api.miljoeportal.dk/"* without the rest of the address, so erase *"download/dai/BES_NATURTYPER_SHAPE.zip"*.

I was thinking something like keep everything between `https://` and the first `/` after that.

These are the variations I have tried so far:

```r
# 1
URLS <- gsub(".*?//", "", URLS)

# 2
URLS <- gsub("http://", "", URLS)

# 3
URLS <- gsub(".*?//", "", URLS)

# 4
URLS <- gsub("/.*", "", URLS)
```

None of which works.

Comment: I am sorry but I can't find the answer for this question in the linked duplicated question?! Could someone point me there. Otherwise I advocate to undelete @akrun s answer that clearly answers this question.

Comment: Obligatory:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a solution that was possible only with the help of @akrun (many thanks) using lookaround regex:

```
sapply(strsplit(URLS, "(?<=\\w/).", perl = TRUE), `[`, 1)
```

```
[1] "https://arealdata-api.miljoeportal.dk/"         "https://download.kortforsyningen.dk/"           "https://b0902-prod-dist-app.azurewebsites.net/"
 [4] "https://sit-ftp.statens-it.dk/"                 "https://arealdata.miljoeportal.dk/"             "https://miljoegis3.mim.dk/"                    
 [7] "https://envs.au.dk/"                            "https://arealdata-api.miljoeportal.dk/"         "https://wfs2-miljoegis.mim.dk/"                
[10] "httphttps://datasets.catalogue.data.gov.dk/"    "https://ens.dk/"                                "https://miljoegis.mim.dk/"                     
[13] "https://www.marineregions.org/"                 "https://CRAN.R-project.org/"                    "https://miljoegis3.mim.dk/"                    
[16] "https://landbrugsgeodata.fvm.dk/"
```

Answer (score 3):

We could capture (`(...)`) the substring by matching one or more characters not a `:` (`[^:]+`) from the start (`^`) of the string, followed by the `:` and two slash `//`, followed by characters not a slash and a slash and leave the rest of the characters out of group (`.*`), replace with the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
 sub("^([^:]+://[^/]+/).*", "\\1", URLS)
```

-output

```
[1] "https://arealdata-api.miljoeportal.dk/"         "https://download.kortforsyningen.dk/"          
 [3] "https://b0902-prod-dist-app.azurewebsites.net/" "https://sit-ftp.statens-it.dk/"                
 [5] "https://arealdata.miljoeportal.dk/"             "https://miljoegis3.mim.dk/"                    
 [7] "https://envs.au.dk/"                            "https://arealdata-api.miljoeportal.dk/"        
 [9] "https://wfs2-miljoegis.mim.dk/"                 "httphttps://datasets.catalogue.data.gov.dk/"   
[11] "https://ens.dk/"                                "https://miljoegis.mim.dk/"                     
[13] "https://www.marineregions.org/"                 "https://CRAN.R-project.org/"                   
[15] "https://miljoegis3.mim.dk/"                     "https://landbrugsgeodata.fvm.dk/"
```

Comment: Master if do `sapply(strsplit(x,"\\w+/"), `[`, 1)` , x is the vector, I get almost the answer but I loose the matched regex e.g. `.dk` or `.net`. this is the same if i use `separate` from tidyr with the separator `sep=\\w+/`. So could we separate a string by a separator but keep the separator ?? Many thanks.

Comment: @TarJae perhaps you want a regex lookaround i.e. `sapply(strsplit(URLS, "(?<=\\w/).", perl = TRUE), `[`, 1)`

Answer (score 2):

The other answer provides a better [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) pattern, but I'd match with *https://* as well, instead of simply getting everything from the beginning of the string on top of counting the slashes (see the 10th URL). I provided an alternative here, just for the fun of it.

```r
my_ptrn <- paste(paste0("https://(.*)", 
                        c(".dk", ".net", ".com", ".org")),
                 collapse = "|")

stringr::str_extract(URLS, my_ptrn)
```

```
#>  [1] "https://arealdata-api.miljoeportal.dk"        
#>  [2] "https://download.kortforsyningen.dk"          
#>  [3] "https://b0902-prod-dist-app.azurewebsites.net"
#>  [4] "https://sit-ftp.statens-it.dk"                
#>  [5] "https://arealdata.miljoeportal.dk"            
#>  [6] "https://miljoegis3.mim.dk"                    
#>  [7] "https://envs.au.dk"                           
#>  [8] "https://arealdata-api.miljoeportal.dk"        
#>  [9] "https://wfs2-miljoegis.mim.dk"                
#> [10] "https://datasets.catalogue.data.gov.dk"       
#> [11] "https://ens.dk"                               
#> [12] "https://miljoegis.mim.dk"                     
#> [13] "https://www.marineregions.org"                
#> [14] "https://CRAN.R-project.org"                   
#> [15] "https://miljoegis3.mim.dk"                    
#> [16] "https://landbrugsgeodata.fvm.dk"
```